# Is there a problem with nextjs 12.2 middleware and docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, middleware

I just updated my nextJS versión to 12.2 to use the stable versión of its middleware. I chaged _middleware.ts to middleware.ts, and put it at the pages folder (Like the documentation says).
If I run it on my local machine, it works perfectly, but when I run it on my docker image the middleware is ignored and nothing inside it is executed.

I have tried running the `next dev` and it works great. Then I've tried to run `next build` and `next start` to run the "compiled" version of the code, locally, and it's still working fine.

I used console.log in the middleware to ensure that the code is executed and I can not see any of them, and the variables that are attached at the params are not loaded.

I am using this configuration:

- Dev machine:
  Node versión 14.21.2
  Yarn versión 1.22.19
- Docker imagen:
  Image created from keymetrics/pm2:14-alpine

All the files needed to run the application, are copied correctly, and the middleware worked fine at nextJS version 12.0.7 which has the middleware at beta version, and we need to use the _middleware.ts file.

If you need more data about some, please tell me and I update the post.

Comment: Have you managed to identify the problem? I'm facing the same issue :(

Comment: same issue, how to fix it?